# Structuring points on a map for search in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app that stores locations on a map. I want users to be able to do a search for all locations within X miles and to be able to search by name. I know I can use the trig functions to find the range of coordinates accepted, but I'm not sure how to structure the data so that I can use the `queryStarting(atValue: Any?, childKey: String?)` and
`queryEnding(atValue: Any?, childKey: String?)` 
member functions to search both in a coordinate radius and by the name of each location.

Comment: For map related ish, have you had a look at geoquery? https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js

Comment: I have not, but will now. Thanks!